# How does the control flow with these multiple calls to a recursive function?

Tags: c, recursion

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 void display(int n)
 {
     if(n)
     {
        display(n-1);               
        printf("display 1\n"); 
        display(n-1);
        printf("display 2 ");
     }
 }

 int main()
 {
     display(5);
     return 0;
 }
```

How is the control switching between `display_1` and `display_2`?

What is the relation between these two calls and how are they working here?

I am very familiar with the *factorial* program using recursion. But am getting confused here to judge whether `display_1` will call `display_2` or vice versa.

The output of the code:

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Ignore image description part XD.But that link has output of the code

Comment: What are you referring to when you write `display_1` and `display_2`? Your code has only one function `display()`, and outputs to strings `display 1` and `display 2` (without underscore). There is no "relation" between those, just a function that calls itself, and two strings written to stdout.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple possibilities to explore the control flow (as long as there is no multithreading or multiprocessing which isn't in this case).

One option would be to execute your sample code step by step in a debugger. Another option could be "printf" debugging. For this, I added some `printf()`s to your orignal code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display(int n, int depth)
{
  printf("%*sdisplay(%d) entered\n", depth * 4, "", n);
  if (n) {
    printf("%*s1st call display(%d)\n", depth * 4, "", n - 1);
    display(n - 1, depth + 1);               
    printf("display 1\n");
    printf("%*s2nd call display(%d)\n", depth * 4, "", n - 1);
    display(n - 1, depth + 1);
    printf("display 2\n");
  }
  printf("%*sleaving display(%d)\n", depth * 4, "", n);
}

int main(void)
{
  /*
  printf("call display(5)\n");
  display(5, 0);
  */
  printf("call display(2)\n");
  display(2, 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and executed on [*ideone*](https://ideone.com/EQHMCn):

```
call display(2)
    display(2) entered
    1st call display(1)
        display(1) entered
        1st call display(0)
            display(0) entered
            leaving display(0)
display 1
        2nd call display(0)
            display(0) entered
            leaving display(0)
display 2
        leaving display(1)
display 1
    2nd call display(1)
        display(1) entered
        1st call display(0)
            display(0) entered
            leaving display(0)
display 1
        2nd call display(0)
            display(0) entered
            leaving display(0)
display 2
        leaving display(1)
display 2
    leaving display(2)
```

Additionally, I used indentation to visualize the recursion depth.
So, is it still unclear?

Thus, each call of `display()` makes two recursive descends (if `n` not yet `0`) where the called `display()` again makes two recursive descends (if `n` not yet `0`) and so on (until termination of recursion).

A very similar common application of this pattern is the calculation of [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

The traversal of a tree structure is another similar application of this pattern (mentioned in [Tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)). In the case of a [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree), there are two possible recursive calls per step. (In a general tree, there are as many recursive calls as the node has children.)

Comment: Would you mind if I rework your indentation? It could use some more spaces